# onCharacteristicChanged is not called in BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

**What i am doing:**

1. Connecting my Android app to the device using gatt.connect().
2. After connecting, i am discovering all the services.
3. Then, i am enabling the notification on all the control characteristics. It is a successful write.
4. After that, i am trying to write some data on one of those control characteristics, which is a success.
5. The expected behavior is that i should receive a reply on onCharacteristicChanged(), but it is not triggering.

**Connecting:**

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
        mDevice = device;
```

**GATT Callback**

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.i(Constant.BLUETOOTH_GATT_TAG, "Status: " + status);
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            switch (newState) {
                case STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            services = gatt.getServices();
            for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                Log.i("services Discovered", service.getUuid().toString());
            }

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(Constant.UUID_FRANK_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(Constant.UUID_ILLUMINATION_CONTROL_POINT_CHARACTERISTICS);
            Log.d("Notification Enabled", "" + enableNotificationsForCharacteristic(characteristic));
            //getAuthenticated();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            Log.d(CHARACTERISTICS_CHANGED_TAG, "Received from Characteristic UUID");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.d("onCharacteristicWrite", "Value is written...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
            Log.d("onDescriptorWrite", "Descriptior is written...");
            Log.d("onDescriptorWrite" , "" + mBluetoothGatt.readDescriptor(descriptor));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorRead(gatt, descriptor, status);

            Log.d("onDescriptorRead" , "" + status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
        }
    };
```

**Enabling The Notifications:**

```
private boolean enableNotificationsForCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

            if (mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Writing to Characteristic:**

```
private boolean writeToCharacteristic(BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] aValue, boolean aWithResponse) {
        boolean ret = false;

        if (service != null) {
            if (characteristic != null) {
                characteristic.setValue(aValue);
                characteristic.setWriteType(aWithResponse ? BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT : BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                ret = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "writeToCharacteristic() - Characteristic is null! " + service + " - " + characteristic);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "writeToCharacteristic() - Service is null! " + service);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

**What i am expecting:**
After setting notification descriptor, i am getting a GATT_SUCCESS but when i am writing a characteristic, it is not triggering onCharacteristicChanged(). I am expecting it to trigger so that i can read the notification response. The device is behaving properly because i have confirmed the notification using Nordic Connect App

**What have i tried:**

1. Tried verifying the descriptor, to see if it is being written properly. It does.
2. Cross checking the name of services and characteristics. They are all fine.
3. Tried putting delay before write descriptor. It is being written properly.

Can anyone help me? Why it is not triggering onCharacteristicChanged?

Comment: Are you able to slove this?